# In batch file, how to use regex to find last word in a line

Tags: batch-file

str = "The is the end of line"
how to search for the last word "line" in the above string fusing batch script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for %%i in (The is the end of line) do set "TheEnd=%%i"
echo(%TheEnd%
```

Comment: The output is in the variable `%TheEnd%`. You can save it to a file with the echo command: `echo(%TheEnd%>myfile.txt`.

Comment: so without using file, it is not possible like linux [shell/bash]

Comment: What output do you want to store in a variable? What command? Can't help you with linux/bash.

Comment: for eg: Set var=`findstr "name" temp.txt`  [temp.txt consist  multiple lines , out of which one line says "my name is ABC"]  later on find the last word of the line i.e. ABC

Comment: If you want to store more than one result in variables, pleas make a new question. Thanks.